# mongodb2.6 not returning min values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongodb out of which I want to run a query to return minimum `servicecost` for each `serviceType`. The relevant fields are:

```
> db.vendor_master.find({},{"serviceType":1,"servicecost":1,"_id":0})
{ "serviceType" : "Florist", "servicecost" : 10000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Florist", "servicecost" : 10000 }
{ "serviceType" : "DJ", "servicecost" : 10000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Florist", "servicecost" : 10000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Florist", "servicecost" : 10000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Decorator", "servicecost" : 10000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Decorator", "servicecost" : 10000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Decorator", "servicecost" : 12000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Pandit", "servicecost" : 3500 }
{ "serviceType" : "Pandit", "servicecost" : 1000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Pandit", "servicecost" : 5000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Pandit", "servicecost" : 1000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Florist", "servicecost" : 10000 }
{ "serviceType" : "DJ", "servicecost" : 10000 }
{ "serviceType" : "DJ", "servicecost" : 10000 }
{ "serviceType" : "DJ", "servicecost" : 10000 }
{ "serviceType" : "DJ", "servicecost" : 10000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Band", "servicecost" : 1000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Band", "servicecost" : 50000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Band", "servicecost" : 152500 }
{ "serviceType" : "Decorator", "servicecost" : 2000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Decorator", "servicecost" : 25000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Pandit", "servicecost" : 1000 }
{ "serviceType" : "Band", "servicecost" : 12500 }
{ "serviceType" : "Band", "servicecost" : 15000 }
```

I am trying the following query

```
db.vendor_master.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"serviceType",mincost:{$min:"servicecost"}}}])
```

the output is:

```
{ "_id" : "serviceType", "mincost" : "servicecost" }
```

Expected output should be each `serviceType` with minimum `servicecost`.

Any idea where am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) takes one  expression as its operand.

```js
{ $min: <expression> }
```

And expression must be prefixed by the dollar sign `$` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#field-path-and-system-variables):

> Aggregation expressions use [field path](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-field-path) to access fields in the input documents. To specify a field path, use a string that prefixes with a dollar sign `$` the field name or the dotted field name, if the field is in embedded document.

```js
db.vendor_master.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "serviceType",
        "mincost": { "$min": "$servicecost" }
    }}
])
```